# Решить задачу через рекурсию (with cte) , решение должно быть такое же как и при connect by

Tags: sql, oracle, рекурсия

Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку в рекурсии , чтоб она отрабатывала цикл
Моя таблица (имеет цикл, в чем и сама проблема)

```
create table scrubs1(emp_id number, 
  manager_id number, 
  job varchar2(100), 
  salary number);

insert into scrubs1 values (1, null, 'Директор' ,50000);
insert into scrubs1 values (2, 1,'Начальник ОП' ,40000);
insert into scrubs1 values (3, 1,'Главый бухгалтер', null);
insert into scrubs1 values (4, 3,'Бухгалтер' ,30000);
insert into scrubs1 values (5, 2,'Ведущий менеджер', 35000);
insert into scrubs1 values (6, 5,'Менеджер', 20000);
insert into scrubs1 values (7, 5,'Менеджер-стажер', 5000);
insert into scrubs1 values (66, null,'Директор 2', 20000);
insert into scrubs1 values (77, 66,'Менеджер-стажер 2', 5000);

select * from scrubs1

insert into scrubs1 values (10, 11,'Директор 2', 20000);
insert into scrubs1 values (11, 10,'Менеджер-стажер 2', 5000);
```

Решение connect by(Работает идеально, то что оно выводит и должно быть в рекурсии)

```
SELECT lpad(' ', 3*(level-1))||emp_id as Tree,
  sys_connect_by_path (prior job,'\') as "Начальники",
  NVL((select sum(salary) as total
from scrubs1 A
start with a.manager_id= b.emp_id
connect by prior a.emp_id= manager_id),0) as zp
from scrubs1 b
start with manager_id is null
connect by prior emp_id= manager_id
;
```

Рекурсия( из-за цикла в таблице работает некорректно)

```
wiTH t1(job,emp_id, lvl,root_id, path) AS (
  SELECT job,
    emp_id,
    1 AS lvl,
    emp_id AS root_id,
    to_char(' ') AS path
  FROM   scrubs1
  WHERE  manager_id IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t2.job,
   t2.emp_id,
   lvl+1,
   t1.root_id,
   t1.path|| '/' ||t1.job AS path
  FROM scrubs1 t2, t1
  WHERE  t2.manager_id is not null
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY emp_id SET order1
,t2(job,root_id, emp_id, sum_zp, sum_sal) AS 
( SELECT job,
    emp_id as root_id,
    emp_id,
    salary as sum_zp, 
    salary
  FROM   scrubs1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t2.job,
    t2.root_id,
    t1.emp_id,
    sum_zp,
    salary
  FROM scrubs1 t1, t2
  WHERE  t1.manager_id is not null
)
CYCLE emp_id SET lvl TO 'X' DEFAULT '-' 
SELECT
  lPAD(' ', (lvl-1)*2) || t1.emp_id AS tree,
  path, 
  sum_sal
FROM t1 
join (select job, 
        root_id, 
        sum(sum_sal)-max(nvl(sum_zp,0)) as sum_sal
      from t2
      group by root_id, job
     ) t2 on t1.job = t2.job
order by order1
```

Comment: *из-за цикла в таблице работает некорректно* А с чего бы ему работать корректно, если всё, что есть общего между запросами - это имя используемой таблицы. Логика запросов - ничего общего.

Comment: Вот первый запрос, переписанный на рекурсивный CTE в синтаксисе MySQL: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5683b6cc703e52e2efb7048a30ae6254